Exporting multiple EVI masked Images in Google Earth Engine
Introduction:
The following is a script I have prepared for exporting multiple EVI images for a given date range. NDWI index was implemented to identify water pixels and mask them out thus resulting in EVI images without water pixels.
Problem:
Two issue were found upon inspecting the exported outputs:

Some images when loading it in a desktop GIS software (ArcGIS 10.8) shows the image having a range from inf - 1.79769e+308 as max and min respectively.

The rest of the images with the EVI range between -1 to +1 range shows water pixels, indicating that it did not mask out water areas. Strangely when viewing it on earth engine using Map.addLayer(waterMaskedEVI.first()), I can see the desired output I wanted.


Script:
// Function to calculate EVI
function addEVI(image) {
  var evi = image.expression(
    '2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 2.5 * RED + 1))', {
      'NIR': image.select('B8'),
      'RED': image.select('B4')
    }).rename('evi');
  return image.addBands(evi);
}

// Function to calculate NDWI
function addNDWI(image) {
  var ndwi = image.expression(
    '(GREEN - SWIR1) / (GREEN + SWIR1)', {
      'GREEN': image.select('B3'),
      'SWIR1': image.select('B8A')
    }).rename('ndwi');
  return image.addBands(ndwi);
}

// Function to mask clouds
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
      qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
      .select("B.*")
      .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
}

// Function to mask water pixels
function maskWater(image) {
  var waterMask = image.select('ndwi').gt(0);
  return image.updateMask(waterMask.not()).select('evi');
}

// Load Sentinel-2 image collection
var originalCollection = s2.filterDate("2019-01-01", "2019-12-31")
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(geometry))
  .map(maskS2clouds)
  .map(addEVI)
  .map(addNDWI);

// Mask water pixels from the EVI images
var waterMaskedEVI = originalCollection.map(maskWater);

// Export configuration
var exportArgs = {
  folder: "Sentinel_2_EVI-Masked",
  region: geometry,
  scale: 10,
  crs: 'EPSG:32644',
  fileFormat: "GeoTIFF",
  formatOptions: {
    cloudOptimized: true
  }
};

// Export each image in the collection with formatted filename
var imageList = waterMaskedEVI.toList(waterMaskedEVI.size());
var numImages = imageList.size().getInfo();
for (var i = 0; i < numImages; i++) {
  var image = ee.Image(imageList.get(i));
  var date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start'));
  var formattedDate = date.format('yyyyMMdd'); // Format the date as desired
  exportArgs.image = image;
  exportArgs.fileNamePrefix = 'EVI_' + formattedDate.getInfo();
  Export.image.toDrive(exportArgs);
}

// Print the image list (for reference)
print(imageList);

